# What variables are available in a Visual Studio 2010 .testsettings file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

I thought maybe that variables like $(Configuration) and $(Platform) might be available for use in Deployment paths as it seems to take and use $(OutDir).  Unfortunately neither $(Configuration) nor $(Platform) are recognized.  Has anybody seen documentation on which variables are allowed in Deployment paths in these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DeploymentItemAttribute Class](http://DeploymentItemAttribute%20Class)

The only var mentioned in the remarks section is the OutDir.  There are two additional properties on the class and neither would be useful to you probably.  It doesn't look like, from reading this article, that you can't access any additional variables in the .testsettings file.

You could always try throwing in a few additional ones [from this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs%28loband%29.aspx) but from what I have read it looks like you won't have access to the known build properties.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I'll have to look for another way to solve my problem.  Thanks!